# Увеличение id по выполнении SQL-запроса

Tags: c#, sql

Всем привет, у меня есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT URL FROM t_links ORDER BY ID = ID + 1 DESC
```

Так вот, этот запрос делается при срабатывании таймера, каждый раз как к таймеру обращаются, ID должно увеличиваться на 1, но это почему-то происходит только 1 раз :( Подскажите как исправить ошибку...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORDER BY служит для указания сортировки, а не для изменения значения.
Если вам нужно менять значения в таблице, используйте оператор UPDATE.

Странно, что запрос не вызывает ошибки синтаксиса. Интересно, какая это СУБД?

Comment: Не знаю, просто база phpmyadmin. Просто мне надо сделать сортировку по увеличению, и после то тем ссылкам уже переходить(ID = ID + 1)

Comment: Значит MySQL.
Ошибку он не генерит, но и что делает непонятно. Напишите нормально:

SELECT URL FROM t_links ORDER BY ID DESC

А затем в коде C# напишите обработчик.

Comment: Да я пробовал, не получается. Мне нужно чтобы среди ID не было дырок, и ID увеличивался, после можно было считать ID, а по нему уже считывать другие данные из данной ячейки.

Comment: Зачем Вам, чтобы среди ID не было дырок?

Comment: @Angus123 
Какая разница, есть дыры или нет, если вам нужно следующее значение в порядке обхода курсора (рекордсета).
Если курсор не сохраняется между вызовами, запоминайте где-нибудь текущее значение и получайте следующее, например, так:

SELECT URL, ID FROM t_links where ID = (select max(ID) from t_links where id < предыдущее_значение_ID)

Comment: Мне нужно сделать механизм авто-сёрфинга. Программа ищет ID'шки, после чего по ним считывает URL и передает его в переменную, но при повторном обращении к таймеру, ID увеличивается на 1.

Comment: Как сделать без пропусков, я вам уже говорил.

Comment: Да это у меня работает, вот теперь осталось сделать так чтобы **ID'шки при срабатывании таймера увеличивались на 1**